# Handling dates java.util, dates java.sql and SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, oracle, date, jdbc

I have trouble at handling different formats of dates in a program.

As it it now, my query is executed, but i get dates from DB in a YYYY-MM-DD format.
I want them in DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm format.

In a SQL file, dates are defined like this (in an INSERT INTO instruction) :

```
to_date('2015/05/15 12:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi')
```

In my java code, i try to make the user choose a date (Date object is a java.util.date) :

```
DateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm", Locale.FRENCH);
String dateString;
dateString = sc.nextLine();
Date upperDate = formater.parse(dateString);
// a "lowerDate is also that way.

    List<Train> listTrains = new ArrayList<>();
            listTrains = manager.WhenTrain(departure_city, arrival_city, upperDate, lowerDate);

for(int i = 0; i<liste.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(listTrains.get(i));
    }
```

In a method, i try to get values corresponding to various conditions, among them, dates, so i have :

In the constructor and fields :

```
    private PreparedStatement AllTrains;
    private PreparedStatement LookForDepartureStation;

    AllTrains = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Trains"
                    + "WHERE departure = ? AND arrival = ? AND departurehour BETWEEN ? AND ?"); // Trains is a view, joining several table
 LookForDepartureStation = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * from Journey where departure = ?");
```

In another method :

```
    public List<Train> WhenTrain(String departureStation, String arrivalStation, java.util.Date dateBefore, java.util.Date dateAfter) {

        ArrayList<Train> TrainList= new ArrayList<>();

        try {


            java.sql.Date begin = new java.sql.Date(dateBefore.getTime());
            java.sql.Date end = new java.sql.Date(dateAfter.getTime());


            LookForDepartureStation.setString(1, departureStation);
            ResultSet test1 = LookForDepartureStation.executeQuery();

            if(test1.next()){

                  LookForDepartureStation.close();
                  LookForArrivalStation.setString(1, arrivalStation);
                  ResultSet test2 = LookForArrivalStation.executeQuery();

                  if(test2.next()) {
                      LookForArrivalStation.close();

                      AllTrains.setString(1, departureStation);
                      AllTrains.setString(2, arrivalStation);
                      AllTrains.setDate(3, begin);
                      AllTrains.setDate(4, end);

                      ResultSet rs = AllTrains.executeQuery();

                         while(rs.next()){
                               TrainList.add(new Train(rs.getInt(1), 

    rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getDate(4), rs.getDate(5))); 
    // Train is an object to take all those.
    // AllTrains contains  TrainID (an oracle integer), departure (varchar2), arrival (varchar2), departurehour (sql oracle DATE), arrivalhour (sql oracle DATE)


           }
                   // AllTrains.close();
                     return ListeTrains;
                  }
                  else {
                      System.out.println("wrong input on arrival station");
                    //  AllTrains.close();
TrainApp.Alltrains(this);
                      return TrainList;
                  }
            } 
            else {
               System.out.println("wrong input on departure station");

               return TrainList;
            }

        } catch (SQLException error) {
            error.printStackTrace();

           return TrainList;
      }
             catch(NullPointerException e) {
              System.out.println("Station not found");
              e.printStackTrace();
              TrainApp.Alltrains(this); // calling back static method to try again the input.
               return TrainList;
          }

}
```

When i try to pass Upperdate in the method, debugger shows that the variable contains : "1 janv. 0003 00:00:00" (I tried with 03-11-1993 actually). Moreover i don't think it will put the date i want in the Train object, i think i messed that up too.

The program ends without showing me what is in the list (the instructions after the method call, as you see in the 2nd code quote here).

Comment: You mention "debugger show me weird date" - is this the PL/SQL debugger or the Java debugger? Also - you're talking about using a date formatted as "03-11-1993", but your DateFormatter is set up for "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm". The match between the "weird" year of 0003 and the leading "03" in your date string seems interesting...

Comment: Java Debugger. After you comment, i changed my dateformatter and it's way better. Now, i got a result (which is already a progress), but i don't have minutes and hour. My DB dates are formatted with minutes and hours. I'm trying to use Locale to format my SimpleDateFormat so when i parse it in util.Date and in sql.Date after, it takes the minutes too.

Comment: If I recall correctly, Java Date types *only* contain the date - no hour/minute/second fields. I believe you need to use one of the Timestamp types, which combine Date and Time fields (Java experts, please chime in). Best of luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing the values of upperDate and lowerDate it's hard to see why they are not parsed correctly.

The problem with the query is that `java.sql.Date` rounds the `java.util.Date` value in input to the day, i.e. it resets the time part. You must use `java.sql.TimeStamp` if you want to query and retrieve the correct results with the time part. Try change `begin` and `end` type to `java.sql.TimeStamp` and  `rs.getDate(4), rs.getDate(5)` to `rs.getTimestamp(4), rs.getTimestamp(5)`

The misunderstanding usually starts because the type Date in Oracle contains also the time part, but in other RDBMS the date type represents "only" a date

Comment: I was just editing while you were writting. No matter what date i use for UpperDate and LowerDate, debbugger show me "1 janv. 0003 00:00:00" when i pass them as arguments in the method.

Comment: try yo put some log statements before and inside the method and try to find where the bug is. the code you posted shows two different variables: UpperDate and upperDate, a typo?

Comment: Yes, a typo. I try catch errors on the method call, nothing. I tried to print what's inside the list in the method after receiving the datas from the resultSet, nothing. I tried to print "yolo" in the method, nothing...

Comment: After further search, rs.next() is always false. My guess is it's because i send the wrong type of date to the preparedStatement. Why ? Because, as debugger said, upperDate and lowerDate always value something like 1 janv. 0003 00:00:00 (instead of 3-11-1993) or 30 déc. 0020 00:00:00 (instead of (21-02-2020), etc...

Comment: Most problems solved. I understand what you mean in you reply, but how can i put a util.date in a sql.timestamp ?? I thought i was using getTime() to give a Hour/Min part and not round anything.